# I am not getting linked list ouput

Tags: c++, linked-list

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
  int data;
  Node* link;
};

int main(){
  Node * A;
  A=NULL;
  Node* temp=new Node(); // first node;
  temp->data=4;
  temp->link=NULL;
  A=temp;

  temp=new Node();
  temp->data=5;
  temp->link=NULL;

  Node* temp1=A;
  while(temp1->link!=NULL){
    cout<<temp1->data;
    temp1=temp1->link;
  }
}
```

The given program is not showing all the elements of the linked list. I am having problem in identifying the error. At first I initialized the head with a `null` value then made a temporary variable and assigned it an integer value and pointer to the next node.

Comment: You are not linking the Node elements

Comment: Link of a first node is set to NULL here: temp->link=NULL; (before A=temp;)  You should change A's link to temp after setting it second time.

Answer (score 0):

Link list is nothing but a chain of Node attached with each other by link.

Add the link =>

```
A->link = temp;
```

Before the below statement:

```
Node* temp1 = A;
```

Below list structure will be created:
 [4 | -]-->[5 | NULL]

You have to print the last node at the end.

Comment: still not printing the output..could uh please compile and send it to me at rajeevshukla255@gmail.com